# How to access JavaScript built elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, element

I wanted to create a file upload feature in my application. Normally my form contains 1 file field. But I want to let users to have more if they need. So I created it in this way:

**HTML**

```
<div class="att" id="c1">
    <input type="file" name="c1" size="200" /><br>
    <input type="button" value="Add more files" id="more" />
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#more').on('click',function(){
    q = $('.att').length;
    c = $('#c1').html();
    n = q + 1;
    f = c.replace('c1','c'+n);
    $('#c'+q).after('<div>'+f+'</div>');
})
```

You can see my codes live demo [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWpawO).

Up to now, everything is working well. But the problem I have is accessing to new JavaScript built elements for naming them. I need to have file fields with names like c1, c2, c3, ... But all new created elements are getting their names as "c2". It seems my code has some problems to calculate length of ".att" elements because just one of them are HTML native element, and others built with JavaScript.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: `$('.att').length` will always be 1.. you are not appending `<div class="att" id="c1">` element..

Comment: delegated event handling is what you need, I think

Comment: @JaromandaX What  delegation need to do with this?

Comment: perhaps nothing, I misread the title of the question

Comment: @Ouroborus, Find _"id="c1""_ in page..

Comment: @DhavalMarthak — Event delegation is definitely related to this post :) DOM is being updated..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3xua0d3v/

Comment: @Rayon your code in jsfiddle could not set names as I need. All of them still having "c2" name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Rayon said, you are getting the `innerHTML` by using jQuery

```
c = $('#c1').html();
```

You have to get `outerHTML` to have the attributes with you also.
And you need regex replace `/c1/g` to replace all strings occurred.
Your code should be like this:

```
$('#more').on('click',function(){
    q = $('.att').length;
    c = $('#c1')[0].outerHTML;
    n = q + 1;
    f = c.replace(/c1/g,'c'+n);
    $('#c'+q).after(f);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out previously by Rayon and other; the problem is by calling `.html()` we get the inner html of the DOM element and not the html of that specific DOM element. So only file element were getting added each time and not its container element. Hence the count returned by  `$('.att').length` was coming as 1. 
To overcome that you may try following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#more').on('click',function(){
        q = $('.att').length;
        c = $('#c1').html();

        n = q + 1;
        f = c.replace('c1','c'+n);

        $('#c'+q).after('<div class="att" id="c'+n+'" >'+f+'</div>'); //instead of putting new file element in blank div; lets add attrs like class and id to it

    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a better idea to update your input as following:

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" multiple />
```

And use `FormData()` programmatically to rename your files when posting.

Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Nice idea Amir. But it is not the answer of my question. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need small correction you missed to add `class` and `id` to new `div` which you are adding

```
    $('#c'+q).after('<div class="att" id="c'+n +'">'+f+'</div>');
```

**Corrected Example**

```js
$('#more').on('click',function(){
        q = $('.att').length;
        c = $('#c1').html();
        n = q + 1; 
        f = c.replace('c1','c'+n);
        $('#c'+q).after('<div class="att" id="c'+n +'">'+f+'</div>');  console.log(f);
    })
```

```css
input[type=file] {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="att" id="c1">
    <input type="file" name="c1" size="200" />
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Add more files" id="more" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#more').on('click', function() {
  var q = $('.att').length;
  c = $('[name="c1"]').clone().get(0).outerHTML;
  n = q + 1;
  f = c.replace('c1', 'c' + n);
  $('#c' + q).after('<div class="att" id="c'+n+'">' + f + '</div>');
});
```

```css
input[type=file] {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="att" id="c1">
  <input type="file" name="c1" size="200" />
  <br>

</div>
<input type="button" value="Add more files" id="more" />
```